# Minor alignment issue in the blog pagination icons

Tags: bug, design, blog, pagination, icons

There is a minor alignment issue in the blog's pagination icons.

The previous and next page icons in the [authors page](https://stackoverflow.blog/authors/page/2/), [articles page](https://stackoverflow.blog/tags/cc-wiki-dump/page/2/) are partially displayed in the pagination section, which is in the bottom of the page.

**Authors page:**

> [image: Authors page]

**Articles page:**

> [image: Tags]

Answer (score 2):

The fix is quite simple:

When I change the height property of `.posts-navigation` in the CSS from 10 to 15, as in below screenshot

[image]

The bottom of the arrow alligns with the bottom of the word "Previous", the text is however now slightly smaller in height then the arrow is.

[image]